# Multicolumn cells in org-mode tables

Tags: org-mode, org-table, table

Is it possible to merge two or more cells in an org-mode table like when using `\multicolumn{}{}{}` or `\multirow{}{}{}` in LaTeX?

Something like this does not work:

```
|------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------|
|            |             Singular            | Plural      |
|            +-----------+----------+----------+-------------|
|            | Masculine | Neuter   | Feminine | All genders |
|------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------|
| Nominative | *der*     | *das*    | *die*    | *die*       |
| Accusative | *den*     | *das*    | *die*    | *die*       |
| Dative     | *dem*     | *dem*    | *der*    | *denen*     |
| Genetive   | *dessen*  | *dessen* | *deren*  | *deren*     |
|------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------|
```

Is there a way to construct such a table in org-mode?

Comment: Not as far as I know, but there's [`table-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TableMode).

Comment: @wvxvw Interesting. Is it possible to integrate these tables within org-mode, perhaps even as a minor mode or between `#+BEGIN_SRC` and `#+END_SRC` tags?

Comment: I'd try `#+begin_src table` but you'd need to handle the exporting somehow, and that sounds like a lot of trouble, unless there's already an exporeter for that...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As @wvxvw points out, you can use [`table.el`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Text-Based-Tables.html#Text-Based-Tables) by Takaaki Ota.  There is some built-in support for this in org-mode (see [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Cooperation.html#Cooperation)). Your example can be easily translated to `table.el` syntax by replacing some `|` with `+`:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+
|            |             Singular            | Plural      |
|            +-----------+----------+----------+-------------+
|            | Masculine | Neuter   | Feminine | All genders |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+
| Nominative | *der*     | *das*    | *die*    | *die*       |
| Accusative | *den*     | *das*    | *die*    | *die*       |
| Dative     | *dem*     | *dem*    | *der*    | *denen*     |
| Genitive   | *dessen*  | *dessen* | *deren*  | *deren*     |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

The table can be edited using `C-c '` and it exports fine with the HTML and LaTeX backends, *except* that org-mode syntax (such as using asterisks for bold) inside the cells is not recognised. Here is an example of rendered LaTeX export:
[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. As for bold type, the `<b></b>` tag works just fine

Comment: The sentence "Your example can be easily translated to table.el syntax by replacing some | with +:" could be understood as recommending manual translation; but I think that it is better to use the command org-table-create-with-table\.el, bound in Org Mode to ‘C-c ~’

Comment: Yes, I was not aware of that command - thank you!  Although in this particular case the OP is starting with something that is neither a legal `org-mode` table nor a legal `table.el` table, so I doesn't work cleanly.

Comment: What if I need latex fragments inside the table?