# how can i split a cell in org-mode table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I would like to create a table like so.

```
| field 1 | field 2    | field 3        | field 4 |
|         |------+-----|-----+-----+----|         |
|         | sub 1|sub2 | xx  | yy  | zz |         |
|---------+------+-----+-----+-----+----+---------|
|         |      |     |     |     |    |         |
|         |      |     |     |     |    |         |
```

Is there any way that emacs org mode to create such a table.?

Answer (score 0):

There is a table.el program written by takota that was cited as a solution to this problem on January of 2015 [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/multicolumn-cells-in-org-mode-tables/7313#7313).

I tried it out, and it seemed to be closer to working in emacs 22 than in emacs 24. I'm on a mac, so I have both versions installed.

I've been messing around with it for over an hour and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

table.el can be downloaded from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/table/files/).

Comment: i am new to emacs, just migrated from vim. should i just extract `table-1.5.54.el.gz` and paste it as `table.el` inside `.emacs/` folder ?

Comment: table.el is installed by default on the latest emacs.

Comment: im sorry, im new to emacs, and im running `emacs 24.3.1`. if it is installed by default, how do i call them.