# latex inside table using table.el in org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table, table

I am trying to achieve multicolumn cells in org-mode tables like in [Multicolumn cells in org-mode tables](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/multicolumn-cells-in-org-mode-tables), but with Latex inside the cells.

```
  * Minimal Example
  +------------+-----------+--------------+
  |            |           \pi            |
  |            +-------------+------------+
  |            |$\pi$        |            |
  +------------+----+--------+------+-----+
```

I found https://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-LaTeX-export.html and tried

```
  #+ATTR_LATEX: :mode math
```

and

```
  #+ATTR_LATEX: :mode math-inline
```

but no success.

The exported tex in the tex file is

```
    $\backslash$pi
    \$$\backslash$pi\$.
```

Can I protect the string in the cell?
Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, Org mode treats `table.el` tables as black boxes: it does not look inside them and in particular, it does not do the translation to LaTeX. That is done by a `table.el` function called `table-generate-source` which can translate the table into a number of languages (including html and LaTeX) but it has limitations. In particular, it escapes `\ ` and `$` indiscriminately, so it seems it cannot handle math mode at all.