# Merge two cells in an org table

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-table

I basically stumbled onto this [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616460/merge-cells-in-org-mode-tables) how to merge cells in an org-table. This would be very useful to create a header, something like:

```
|Merged header|
|----+--------|
|  / |  <     |
|  1 |  2     |
|  3 |  5     |
| 23 | 14     |
```

Is this possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/multicolumn-cells-in-org-mode-tables?rq=1

Comment: There's around 4 years between the posts so I'd like to hear if any update has been made on that.

Comment: The situation is the same: "native" org-mode tables don't support this functionality, table.el tables do, but they are minimally supported by org-mode. The linked questions/answers are still accurate AFAIK.

Comment: @NickD Too bad, thanks for the info !